# spark: Attempted to use Broadcast after it was destroyed

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following code works

```
 @throws(classOf[IKodaMLException])
 def soMergeTarget1( oldTargetIdx: Double, newTargetIdx: Double): RDDLabeledPoint =
 {
   try
   {
    logger.trace("\n\n--sparseOperationRenameTargetsInNumeriOrder--\n\n")
    val oldTargetIdxb=spark.sparkContext.broadcast(oldTargetIdx)
    val newTargetIdxb=spark.sparkContext.broadcast(newTargetIdx)

    val newdata:RDD[(LabeledPoint,Int,String)] = sparseData.map
    {
      r =>

        val currentLabel: Double = r._1.label
        currentLabel match
        {
          case x if x == oldTargetIdxb.value =>
          val newtrgt=newTargetIdxb.value
          (new LabeledPoint(newtrgt, r._1.features), r._2, r._3)
          case _ => r
        }
    }
  val newtargetmap=ilp.targetMap.filter(e=> !(e._2 == oldTargetIdx))
  oldTargetIdxb.destroy
  newTargetIdxb.destroy
  new RDDLabeledPoint(newdata,copyColumnMap,newtargetmap,ilp.name)
}
```

But, having destroyed the broadcast variables at the end of the method, the `newtrgt` variable in the RDD is also destroyed. 
The trouble is that once the RDD is returned from this method it could be used by any analyst in any code. So, I seem to have lost all control of the broadcast variables.

**Questions:**

If I don't destroy the variables, will spark destroy them when reference to the RDD disappears?

(Perhaps a naive question but....) I tried a little hack `val newtrgt=oldTargetIdxb.value + 1 -1` thinking that might create a new reference that is distinct from the broadcast variable. It didn't work. I must admit that surprised me. Can someone explain why the hack didn't work (I'm not suggesting it was a good idea, but I am curious).

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer [here](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Broadcast-Variable-Life-Cycle-td18683.html)

***Not my answer*** but worth sharing on SO...and why can't I see this in Spark documentation. It's important:

Sean Owen:

> you want to actively unpersist() or destroy() broadcast
>   variables  when they're no longer needed. They can eventually be
>   removed when the  reference on the driver is garbage collected, but
>   you usually would  not want to rely on that.

Follow up question:

> Thank you for the response. The only problem is that actively managing
>   broadcast variables require to return the broadcast variables to the
>   caller if the function that creates the broadcast variables does not
>   contain any action. That is the scope that uses the broadcast
>   variables cannot destroy the broadcast variables in many cases. For
>   example:

==============

```
def perfromTransformation(rdd: RDD[int]) = {
   val sharedMap = sc.broadcast(map)
   rdd.map{id => 
      val localMap = sharedMap.vlaue
      (id, localMap(id))
   }
}

def main = {
    ....
    performTransformation(rdd).toDF("id", "i").write.parquet("dummy_example")
}
```

==============

> In this example above, we cannot destroy the sharedMap before the
>   write.parquet is executed because RDD is evaluated lazily. We will get
>   a exception

Sean Owen:

> Yes, although there's a difference between unpersist and destroy, 
>   you'll hit the same type of question either way. You do indeed have to
>   reason about when you know the broadcast variable is no longer needed 
>   in the face of lazy evaluation, and that's hard.
>
> Sometimes it's obvious and you can take advantage of this to 
>   proactively free resources. You may have to consider restructuring the
>   computation to allow for more resources to be freed, if this is 
>   important to scale.
>
> Keep in mind that things that are computed and cached may be lost and 
>   recomputed even after their parent RDDs were definitely already 
>   computed and don't seem to be needed. This is why unpersist is often 
>   the better thing to call because it allows for variables to be 
>   rebroadcast if needed in this case. Destroy permanently closes the 
>   broadcast.